# How to activate silent mode on Android device

Tags: java, android

```
ArrayList prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(cal, latitude,longitude,timezone);
ArrayList prayerNames = prayers.getTimeNames();
for (int i = 0; i < prayerTimes.size(); i++) {
txtPrayerTimes.append("\n" + prayerNames.get(i) + " - "+ prayerTimes.get(i));
```

[Screenshot of output to this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd3JJ.png)

Now I want to activate silent mode if `current time = fajr time` i.e 03:48 AM

My code so far, which I'm sure is crap...

```
if(getReminingTime()== prayerTimes.get(0)) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peace mode activated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
AudioManager audioManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}}}

private String getReminingTime(){
String delegate = "hh:mm aaa";
return  (String) DateFormat.format(delegate,Calendar.getInstance().getTime());}
```

What is the correct way to enable silent mode on the device?

Comment: Presumably you'll also want to revert to the previous ringer mode after these quiet periods end...?

Comment: There are several questions here on SO that already cover this - try this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+enable+silent+mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to enable media sound even in silent mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798758/how-to-enable-media-sound-even-in-silent-mode)